# EF Core 7 Mapping

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables that look like this.

---

### TABLE 1

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompanyMap](
    [AMLI_COMPANY]
```

---

### TABLE 2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies](
    [CompanyCode]
```

---

The parent/child relationship should look like this.

```
Select *
From CompanyMap
Inner Join Companies ON CompanyMap.AMLI_COMPANY = Companies.CompanyCode
```

---

### I am catching back up on EF Code

How would I map these relationships with different column names.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

            modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyMapDO>()
                .HasOne(c => c.COMPANY)
                .WithOne(c => c.COMPANY_MAP)
                .HasForeignKey("")
```

Since they have different column names for the parent/child foreign key relationships.

I am not sure how to complete the syntax here.

Can someone show me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one

Comment: Please, post your full tables and entities so you can receive better guidance.

Comment: Table Schema https://ibb.co/92WqQ5f

Comment: Entity CompanyMapDO - https://ibb.co/B2cSYsF

Comment: Entity CompanyDO https://ibb.co/HqKBmRC